# Algebraic functions on transcendental numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, transcendental-numbers

An algebraic function of an algebraic number yields an algebraic number, but does an algebraic function of a transcendental number always yield a transcendental number?

Comment: If by "algebraic" function you mean a non-constant rational function (quotient of polynomials with rational coefficients), then the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: I mean a function including polynomials as well as any other kind of combination under +-*/ of solutions to polynomial equations with rational coefficients.

Comment: That rational functions are closed under all of those operations, so they "cover the waterfront."

Comment: You should state that the algebraic function is not a constant function otherwise it may be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. If $f$ is an algebraic function, then it satisfies an irreducible polynomial $p(x,f(x))=0$ with algebraic coefficients. Plugging in $x=t$, our transcendental number, we see that $p(t,f(t))=0$. But this says that a transcendental number $t$ satisfies a polyonmial with algebraic coefficients. The only way for this to be true is if that polynomial is zero: $p(x,f(t))=0$ for any $x$. But this means that $p(x,y)$ is divisible by $(y-f(t))$, contradicting irreducibility of $p$.